# Should I retrieve records within the new method of a resource? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it okay/best practice to retrieve records within the new method for a resource? Or is there a standard way/design pattern for approaching this?

For example:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new,:create]
  layout "admin", only: [:new]

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

or is it better to do this:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new,:create]
  before_action :index             , only: [:new]
  layout "admin", only: [:new]

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

The reason for doing this is to have a view rendered for `/events/new` that has a form for creating a new event and within the same view having a list of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** -> Your **first** example would be correct. If you want to have all of the events listed along with the form for NEW, then render them in your view.

When you call /events/new it will render /views/events/new.html.erb which, if you look, renders _form.html.erb by calling `render 'form'` You can just render your index action below that if you want to insert @events.

You can also use one of the frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and render the form in one row and the index action below that for easy layout.

Comment: I said second above, but meant the first as that is where you are calling the `@events = Event.all` to be able to render them. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay/best practice to retrieve records within the new method for
>   a resource?

Yes, that is perfectly valid. Using controller actions to retrieve data is the right abstraction level of MVC.

Please never use a controller action as a `before_action` like in your second code example:

```
before_action :index, only: [:new]
```

Use only private methods for before-actions aka before-filters.

If you think you want to DRY this up, you can create a method and use `helper_method` to make it available in your views.